# Getting weird undefined foreach error in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I have this syntax:

```
@php($counter_foreach = 0)
@foreach($memnames as $mem=>$memname)
@php 
            
@endphp 
@endforeach
```

Now when I run this, I get **syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)** error:

[image]

But when I remove `@php @endphp`, and replace it with `html`, the error will be gone!

So what's going wrong here?

Is there anything wrong about using `@php` after `@foreach` in Laravel Blades?

Comment: Forgot to close your first `@php` before the `@foreach`

Comment: @brombeer Correct buddy, but I have seen using php inside blade like this: `@php(DEFINING A VARIABLE)`

Comment: In Laravel5.8? What should this do? Looks like yours outputs `<?php($counter_foreach=0)`. `@foreach` won't get parsed since Laravel thinks it's inside a `@php` block. Have you tried adding `@endphp` before your `@foreach`?

Comment: fyi, depending on what you're trying to do (count the iterations of your foreach??) there's [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) that has this info already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add @endphp everytime you add @php like this:

```
@php($counter_foreach = 0)
@endphp
@foreach($memnames as $mem=>$memname)
@php 
            
@endphp 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to make separate php variable for the iterations, so since you have a foreach loop already your logic should be something like this.

```
@foreach($this as $that) {
   @if ($loop->first)
     // some logic
   @endif

   @if ($loop->last)
    // some logic
   @endif
@endforeach
```

The `$loop` variable is available inside the foreach and you check for the iteration number you need inside, I just added some basic uses. Here is some more useful [documentation](https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel-blade-working-with-loop-variable-in-loop).